# Adding auto login for newly created user breaks login form authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have created a custom `login form` and a `create new account` form in Spring 4.2.0. And they work fine. But now I have implemented auto-login for the newly created user, which successfully logs in the user created. But If I log out and try to log-in again with the same credentials, authentication fails. And authentication is not working for other users also. So the only time a user is able to log in is when it is created. After that authentication fails. Making me think that auto-login code for some reason broke spring login authentication. Take a look at the code below. Any guess why it's happening?

login form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="loginForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
            Username:<form:input path="username" size="30" />
            Password:<form:password path="password" size="30" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form:form>
```

secuirty configuration:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login default-target-url="/home" login-page="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/?error=true" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount"
        access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/createAccount/**"
        access="isAnonymous()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
        access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager id="authManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
</bean>
```

Password Encryption before inserting into database:

```
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newAccountDetails.getPassword()));
```

Auto-login in controller after user is successfully created:

```
@RequestMapping("/createAccount")
public ModelAndView submitCreateAccount(@ModelAttribute("newAccount") NewAccountDetails newAccountDetails) {
    System.out.println(newAccountDetails);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    if (userServices.createUserService(newAccountDetails)) {

        System.out.println("user created successfully");
        try {
            userDetails = userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(newAccountDetails.getUsername());
            System.out.println(userDetails);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                    newAccountDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authManager.authenticate(authToken);
            if (authToken.isAuthenticated()) {
                System.out.println("New User is authenticated");
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                mv.setViewName("redirect:/home");
            } else {
                System.out.println("user not authenticated.");
                mv.setViewName("redirect:/");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("e: " + e);
            mv.setViewName("redirect:/");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("user not created");
        mv.setViewName("redirect:/newaccount");
    }
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the exact same encoder? If you are loading the config twice you end up loading beans 2 times and you get different encoders.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I am using the same encoder. In security config, I have declared PasswordEncoder of type  `BCryptPasswordEncoder` which is used in authentication provider as password-encoder. And for encoding user password before inserting to database, same `PasswordEncoder` is used. So I believe that is not the case. Can you explain the case where config is loaded twice. I will check for that in my code.

Comment: If you load the configuration in both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` you get 2 different instances of the encoder. Another thing is that you create an authentication manager, give it an id but never wire it to Spring Security.

Comment: @M.Deinum No, I load my configurations through `ContextLoaderListener` once. But what do you mean by `never wire it to Spring Security`? I have used authentication manager in my controller method for auto login of new user. so I have autowired authentication manager in the controller using id as `@Qualifier`. so I think that is the only wiring that is required at my end. As of Spring authentication I guess it is taken care by Spring itself. isn't it.

Comment: Correct but you have to tell it that you  have a custom configured authentication manager (or remove the `id` property so that is is automatically used.

Comment: @M.Deinum But the funny thing is, if I remove `id` property from my authentication manager and autowire by just `type`. It throws an error saying `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` and further saying `expected single matching bean but found 3`. So it works only when I use `@Qualifier` to tell spring which authentication manager to use.

Comment: Hence Spring Security is using a different one then you are using, ergo you have to explicitly tell Spring Security which of those 3 to use.

Comment: And how I do that for Spring login authentication ?

Comment: specify the `authentication-manager-ref` property on the root `http` element.

Comment: @M.Deinum That was the problem, two different authentication managers. Setting `authentication-manager-ref` property in `http` element fixed it. Can you post an answer with some explanation of what was happening in the Spring background. So it can help other users in future and avoid spending hours trying to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your own `AuthenticationManager` with a specific `id`. However Spring Security knows nothing about this specific instance and still uses the default `authenticationManager`. Hence for registration and login you are basically using 2 different instances of an `AuthenticationManager`.

To fix this you need to tell Spring Security which one to use, do this by adding `authentication-manager-ref` attribute to the main `http` element.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="<your-authetnication-manager-id>">
```

or by specifing the `alias` on your own `AuthenticationManager`.

```
<security:authentication-manager id="authManager" alias="authenticationManager ">
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-auth-manager for more information.